# Timezone instead of cities in clock applet

Tags: 16.04, time, clock

I use time zones for coordinating worldwide teleconferences. But, I usually forget which city has which time zone.
Would it be possible to have GMT, PST, CET, BST time explicitly available among the entries of the *Choose locations* dialog, in addition to the cities?
I noticed that UTC is already available..

Comment: I have been looking for such functionality as well, but it doesn't seem like this is supported - at least I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: You might like the [Personal World Clock](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personal.html) on TimeAndDate.com. Once you create an account, you can create your own personal world clock, which you add cities to, and there is an option to show the time zone for each city. They also have a [Time Zone Converter](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html), which is super useful.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you. It is indeed very useful. However, I'd like to see it in the Ubuntu clock in the future.